# Use your own csv file instead of json

Tags: r, csv, github

I would like to run locally [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD) repository

However I have my own csv file with data which I would like to use instead of the json example.

How is it possible to make it?

Here and example of data

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2), col = c("before", "after", "before", "after"), text = c("text 3 sentiment","I feel good","Happy","It is a nice day and I feel glad"))
```

Comment: So the question is "How do I convert CSV to JSON?" ?

Comment: @zx8754 maybe yes. I am sorry I am not good with tech

Comment: @zx8754 should the json file have a specific format in column titles?

Comment: There are many online tools to convert csv to json, for example: https://www.csvjson.com/csv2json try them out, see if they work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure... but based off your data...

```
> read.csv2("file.csv") %>% jsonlite::toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "col": "before",
    "text": "text 3 sentiment"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "col": "after",
    "text": "I feel good"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "col": "before",
    "text": "Happy"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "col": "after",
    "text": "It is a nice day and I feel glad"
  }
]
```